# AS3 keyboard event behavior different on OS's

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard

I used a `KeyboardEvent` on a `TextArea`, and I try to do some actions on `>`, `/` char style keypress. My problem is that I do not have an homogeneous method to catch those kind of char.

For example, for a `>` pressed, 
on Mac:

```
String.fromCharCode(event.charCode); // -> ">"
trace(event.keyCode);                // -> 62
```

on Windows:

```
String.fromCharCode(event.charCode); // -> "<"
trace(event.keyCode);                // -> 226
```

I found this on other site:

> Different OS's act differently with the KeyboardEvents because flash just plugs into the already present Keyboard interface of the OS. Note Keyboards act differently between Windows, Mac and Linux.

So what best practice can I used to be consistent for those use cases?

Comment: Hi you have shown > on mac and < on windows - surely it will be different on both platforms anyway. Also you may want to listen to changes to the textfield not the keyboard event alone - that way you will know that user has typed something in the textfield

Comment: thanks 

"you may want to listen to changes to the textfield not the keyboard event alone"

sure... but WTF with charCode?... does not work as expected at all...

Comment: Are you saying that: on mac the > gives different charCode than on windows? from your post you have used > for mac and < for windows so not clear what you up to.

Comment: Yes: on mac the > gives different charCode than on windows.

Comment: I would imagine that keycode could be different, but char code is the code of the current code page e.g. like UTF-8, so it should be exactly the same on any system

Answer (score 0):

you should use the charCode as it will be more accurate as it uses the charset (default UTF-8 that supports ASCII), keycode is the code from the keyboard meaning that you can have different codes to the same keys e.g. minus from the "main" part of kebord and minus from the numeric pad will have diferent codes.

[Understanding the keyCode and charCode properties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64a29-7fdb.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64a29-7fed)